# Spring webflow dojo version

Tags: dojo, spring-webflow

The dijit checkbox does not work (`data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox"`) with latest Chrome browser (`Version 55.0.2883.87 m`) because of a bug which was fixed in dojo 1.10.5. It works perfectly in latest firefox  [dojo bug report](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18950.)

Spring webflow only supports dojo 1.5.

Is there a way to use the latest dojo with spring? Or what else is the best way to make our application fly with chrome again?

Answer (score 1):

here is an idea:

add a new js file somewhere in your head tag after spring dojo file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js"/>" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/javaScript/dojo_extensions.js"/>"></script>
```

create the file, find the correct dojo code for "dijit/form/CheckBox" and copy it there. it should overwrite the 1.5 version